# fastest algorithm to list all words in a puzzle

Tags: algorithm, search

I was asked this question at an interview and I'm curious about the optimal answer. The question is like this: you are given an n x n board filled with letters. a gaming algorithm wants to find and list all the possible words on this board, where "a word" is defined as a string of at least 3 letters, either horizontally or vertically. what's the most time efficient way to do this?

the "word" in this question DOES NOT need to be a real word from a dictionary. the point is to find all strings of acceptable length as FAST as possible. I couldn't think of anything else except for the brutal force approach that traverses through all spaces on the board and find all strings starting with the letter in that space, which requires O(n^3) time. how would you guys do it?

PS. I see this question got downvoted because people don't think there's a better solution. This, however, is a microsoft interview question and my interviewer explicitly told me that my answer was not optimal.

Comment: Just a clarification. A word is simple a string of characters with length greater than or equal to 3? So for example, if my horizontal line was 'abcde', then the algorithm should output, 'abcde', 'abcd', 'bcde', 'abc', 'bcd' and 'cde'?

Comment: I don't think there is a fast method for that, you need to start with every letter and find all the words of length n in all 4 directions.

Comment: @ChrisMansley yes, and also the reverse of all of those. i agree it's a confusing setup but that's what the question was...

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski see the edited question. I think there should be a data structure that you can use, just that most people don't know about it...

Comment: If the goal was just to enumerate all of the possible words, I cannot think of a faster approach. Obviously, there are better or worse ways to implement this brute force algorithm, but the overall complexity would be similar. However, if the goal was to provide a data structure for the gaming algorithm, then maybe a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) approach might be more efficient. Maybe.

Comment: You are not considering the symmetry, for instance these movements in a `NxN` board have a symmetry of 8

Comment: Interview questions sometimes require you to ask the interviewer back on some details; for example, you could say "Well, what does it exactly mean to *list* a word?" And then he says "Whatever you think is best". So you say that your program will not print the word "whittynittyfiddlepumpkin" explicitly, but something like "A word at position (13,15) going right, 24 letters" - then the output will be O(n^3) instead of O(n^4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `m(x) = max {0, x}`. If we use 0-based indices, there are

```
s(x,y) = m(x-1) + m(n-x-2) + m(y-1) + m(n-y-2)
```

words starting at position `(x,y)`. Horizontally, to the left those ending in column `0, 1, ..., y-2` and to the right those ending in column `x+2, x+3, ..., n-1`. Similar for the vertical words.

So at each position there start between `2*(n-3)` and `2*(n-2)` words (inclusive).

More precisely, at position `(x,y)`, there start `n-2` horizontal words if and only if `y = 0` or `y = n-1`, `n-3` words otherwise. That makes `2*(n-2) + (n-2)*(n-3) = (n-1)*(n-2)` horizontal words per row. The number of vertical words per column is the same, so altogether there are

```
2*n*(n-1)*(n-2)
```

not necessarily distinct words in the grid. Assuming a not too small alphabet, the proportion of duplicates is on average not large, so it's impossible to have an algorithm of complexity below `O(n³)`.

If duplicates shall not be considered, that's it, and there remains only the low-level variations of traversing the array.

If duplicates shall be removed, and the target is to list all distinct words as efficiently as possible, the question is what data structure allows to remove the duplicates as efficiently as possible. I can't answer that, but I think a trie would be rather efficient for that.

Comment: Note however, that listing the `O(n^3)` words naively is `O(n^4)`, since the average length for a word. is `O(n)` itself.

Comment: True, but if "listing" means outputting each word separately, there is no way to avoid `O(n^4)`.

Comment: I Agree, it depends on what "listing" exactly means. Anyhow, it is important to note that a brute force algorithm is NOT `O(n^3)` either way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach to the problem in stages:

1. Try finding a given word in a puzzle: You can use DFS to find a word in the puzzle. This would be O(n^2) as we'd have to iterate through every row and column character.
2. Find all given words in a puzzle: If there are x words given, you can use the above algorithm for every word. The complexity would be O(x*n^2).
3. If there are words with same prefix then we will be repeating the work done for searching the prefix. This can be avoided by building a Trie structure for the words given and combine DFS of the trie with DFS of the puzzle.

Here is a rough implementation of the first step in C++:

```
bool FindWordInPuzzle(int i, int j, char nextChar, int nextCharId, string word, int m, int n, bool **mark, char **maze)
{
    int move[8][2] = { 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1 };
    mark[i][j] = 1;

    for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
        int g = i + move[r][0];
        int h = j + move[r][1];

        if (g > 0 && g < m + 2 && h > 0 && h < m + 2 && mark[g][h] == 0 && maze[g][h] == nextChar) {
            nextCharId++;

            if (nextCharId >= word.length()) {
                return true;
            }

            if (FindWordInPuzzle(g, h, word[nextCharId], nextCharId, word, m, n, mark, maze)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool FindWord(char **maze, bool **mark, int m, int n, string word) {
    char currentChar = word[0];
    int currentCharId = 0;
    for (int row = 1; row < m + 2; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col < n+2; col++) {
            if (maze[row][col] == currentChar && mark[row][col] == 0) {
                currentCharId++;
                if (currentCharId >= word.length()) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (FindWordInPuzzle(row, col, word[currentCharId], currentCharId, word, m, n, mark, maze)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            currentCharId = 0;
            currentChar = word[0];
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    string word;
    int m, n;

    cin >> word;
    if (word.length() <= 0) return 0;

    cin >> m >> n;
    char** maze;
    bool **mark;

    // declare arrays
    maze = new char*[m + 2];
    mark = new bool*[m + 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < m + 2; i++) {
        maze[i] = new char[n + 2];
        mark[i] = new bool[n + 2];
    }

    // boundaries
    for (int i = 0; i < m + 2; i++) {
        maze[0][i] = ' ';
            maze[i][0] = ' ';
        maze[0][m + 1] = ' ';
        maze[i][m + 1] = ' ';

        mark[0][i] = 1;
        mark[i][0] = 1;
        mark[0][m + 1] = 1;
            mark[i][m + 1] = 1;

    }

    // get values
    for (int i = 1; i < m + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n + 1; j++) {
            cin >> maze[i][j];
            mark[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    bool val =  FindWord(maze, mark, m, n, word);
    cout << val;
    cin >> word;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here - one: The naive solution **brute force is NOT `O(n^3)`, it is `O(n^4)`**.

Assume you copy each substring to a new entry in a list. You have `O(n^3)` words. However, each of these is `O(n)` (on average) itself, so copying all these substrings to a list is actually `O(n^4)`.

Two:

A more efficient solution will be to maintain a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure, and fill it up using a DFS like traversal from each index in the matrix (to the right and to the down).

This will result in `O(n^3)` solution to fill the trie with the `O(n^3)` words.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saying `O(n^3)`? The board is squared and square is `O(n^2)`.

The code is follows:

```
for(int col=0; col<n-2; ++col) {
    for(int row=0; row<n-2; ++row) {
        // for given (row,col)
        // yield word to right
        // yield word down
        // yield word down-right
    }
}
```

This is `O(3*n^2)`.

If you wish to take reversed too then it will be `O(6*n^2)`

**REAL CODE IN C#**

```
class Program
{
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        char[,] letters = new char[5, 5];
        int counter = 0;

        // filling and printing
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.GetLength(0); ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < letters.GetLength(1); ++j)
            {
                letters[i, j] = alphabet[rnd.Next(alphabet.Length)];
                Console.Write(letters[i,j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }



        // generating "words"

        for (int i = 0; i < letters.GetLength(0)-2; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < letters.GetLength(1)-2; ++j)
            {
                // horizontally
                Console.Write(counter.ToString() + ": ");

                Console.Write(letters[i, j]);
                Console.Write(letters[i, j+1]);
                Console.Write(letters[i, j+2]);

                Console.WriteLine("");
                counter++;

                // vertically
                Console.Write(counter.ToString() + ": ");

                Console.Write(letters[i, j]);
                Console.Write(letters[i+1, j]);
                Console.Write(letters[i+2, j]);

                Console.WriteLine("");
                counter++;

                // diagonally
                Console.Write(counter.ToString() + ": ");

                Console.Write(letters[i , j]);
                Console.Write(letters[i + 1, j+1]);
                Console.Write(letters[i + 2, j+2]);

                Console.WriteLine("");
                counter++;
            }
        }



    }
 }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
LWIDM
OWWGR
APVOM
GKECL
TXCPD
0: LWI
1: LOA
2: LWV
3: WID
4: WWP
5: WWO
6: IDM
7: IWV
8: IGM
9: OWW
10: OAG
11: OPE
12: WWG
13: WPK
14: WVC
15: WGR
16: WVE
17: WOL
18: APV
19: AGT
20: AKC
21: PVO
22: PKX
23: PEP
24: VOM
25: VEC
26: VCD
```

Number of results is 27 = 3*(5-2)^2

Comment: (1) This solution is `O(n^3)` (yield a word to right is `O(n)` itself).  (2) I don't see how it will generate all sub-words, for example if you have in some row the chars `['a','b',c','d']` - how will it generate `['a','b','c']`? Care to elaborate?

Comment: Yield a word is `O(1)` because we always have word length of 3 and constant number of words for each cell. Nothing grows when `n` grows hence the complexity is `const(n)`.

Comment: From the question: `where "a word" is defined as a string of **at least** 3 letters`. In your example, `LWIDM,LWID,WIDM` should also be generated from the first row, and similary 3 more words from each row and column.

Comment: Ah sorry, I am not fluent English, in this case you are probably right.